# How to read frames which are separated by a specific number ? [ffmpeg]

Tags: ffmpeg

I have around 1000 frames in *.png format, which are named like `frame-0.png`, `frame-1.png`, `frame-2.png` and so on. I read them and generate a movie by following command :

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -r 20 -i frame-%00d.png -vcodec mpeg4 -y movie.mp4
```

Let's say I just want to read frames like `frame-0.png`,`frame-20.png`, `frame-40.png` and make a movie out of it. How can I achieve that ?

One possible way I know, is to make movie from all 1000 frames then generate a new movie by skipping frames from the following command :

```
ffmpeg -y -i movie.mp4 -filter:v "select='mod(n,20)'" out.mp4
```

Is there any direct method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The direct way to do this is by using the concat [demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat-1), where the text file only mentions the selected files. Besides being a hack, you no longer get to use the `image2` options. The better way is to combine your present commands.

```
ffmpeg -framerate 20 -i frame-%d.png -vf "select='not(mod(n,20))'" -c:v mpeg4 -y movie.mp4
```

Comment: This works only if all the frames are present. What If I have only `frame-0.png`, `frame-20.png`, `frame-40.png` available.

Comment: Then, you use the demuxer or pipe the images. To pipe, on Win: `cat *.png | ffmpeg -f image2pipe -framerate 1 -i - -r 20 -y out.mp4`

Comment: Command in comment above will also work on Linux & macOS.

Comment: Also, I forgot about image autodetection, so you can likely omit the `-f`.